# Multiple Xpath elements in one line of code

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to add multiple Xpath elements to one line of code instead of many lines. If I use "and" it prints index [2], if I use "or" it prints index [1]. Is there any way to possibly shorten this like by using //pre["text()"])[1],[2],[3] and so on?

```
text = requests.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])[1]' and '(//pre["text()"])[2]').text

print(text)
```

Works fine if I use:

```
text = requests.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])[1]').text


text1 = requests.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])[2]').text

print(text + "\n" + text1)
```

I know this is a bit sloppy but this works:

```
    for url in url:

        requests.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)
        print(requests.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])][position() < 3]').text)

for ele in requests.find_elements(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])[1]' and '(//pre["text()"])[2]'):

print(ele.text)
```

requests.close

Now when I go to Write file I get the following error:

```
file.write(ele)
```

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not WebElement

```
file.write(str(ele))
```

writes:
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8107435773e0b799c349347bedc10eba", element="96C16BB8CF5B5DA622C6454400F1E827_element_15")>

Any clue as to how to save ele.text (text of the elements) to a .txt file? I've tried multiple ways and searched the web. I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what XPath API you are using, but I would suspect that the function "requests.find_element" is suitable when you want to find a single element, and that there is some other function or method for selecting multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
(//pre[text()])[position() &lt; 3]
```

Will select the first 2 pre elements that have a text-node

Comment: The following prints index [1]

    text = requests.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])[position() < 3]').text

The following prints index [2]

    text = requests.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])[position() > 3]').text

Still having the same issue, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I fixed the issues I was having with the following:

```
for url in url:

requests.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
print(requests.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])[position() < 3]').text)

for ele in requests.find_elements(By.XPATH, '(//pre["text()"])[1]' and '(//pre["text()"])[2]'):

print(ele.text)
ele = ele.text
requests.close
```

To solve the issue I was having with saving ele.text I simply Declared:

```
ele = ele.text
```